# unroll functionality in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there an unroll function in Tensorflow where a Matrix is converted to vector.

Example :

Matrix `[1 2 3; 4 5 6;]` is 'unrolled' to a Vector `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`

Looking at the math operations this does not seem to be available : https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tf.reshape(a, shape=[-1])` will "unroll" tensor `a` into vector using row-major order. If you want different order, you could `tf.transpose` first

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = tf.reshape(a, shape=[-1])
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(b)  # => array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (Note: I'm not familiar with this domain, so this answer may actually be simple enough to make an explanation, and thus downvotes, unnecessary. You may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)